# Where does ipad store store icloud file created in windows?

Tags: windows, ipad, data-recovery

The MacOS stores `icloud drive` files locally in `~/Library/Mobile Documents`. Where does Ipad and windows store these files by default?

I found a directory in windows `c:\users\<username>\icooud drive`, which is supposed to store the file locally. I tested this by deleting synced file in ipad then try recovering file at this location. The recovery tools (recuva and r-studio) could not find files in windows machine deleted from icloud. They could easily find files in other directories.

I want to extend a program to recover accidentally deleted icloud files in ipad and windows. There are solutions (like Dr.fone) which can recover photos, contact information etc in ipad. But it cannot recover other files like word documents.

May be I am searching in in wrong location. May be icloud saves file in another format. How can I recover deleted icloud files from hard disk data recovery tool. Can anyone suggest where do I need to look and how to look?

Comment: The iCloud client may be doing a secure delete; recovery may be impossible.

Comment: I was able to undelete deleted photos, contacts, notes and bookmarks. That means it is not doing secure delete. icloud is not using TRUNK command, so undelete must be possible. There might be way by which I can undelete other files like word document synced from other devices through icloud drive. But I could not find any current software to do that.